# New line in grep result

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple script, something along the lines of:

```
for i in $(VBoxManaged list runningvms); do
  VBoxManage guestproperty get $i "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/1/V4/IP"
done
```

From the command line:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
"Windows 7" {1234sdfgh-sdfg-ertyu-...}
"Ubuntu 14.04 Server" {09876yhnkli-sdfg-qwert...}
```

The problem is enclosing this command in $() seems to add line breaks.

For example, the for loop above produces:

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '"Windows'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '7"'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
Value: 192.168.8.110
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '"Ubuntu'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '14.04'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Server"'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
```

The following for loop also produces unexpected results:

```
for i in $(VBoxManage list runningvms); do echo $i; done
"Windows
7"
{1234sdfgh-sdfg-ertyu-...}
"Ubuntu
14.04
Server"
{09876yhnkli-sdfg-qwert...}
```

I've tried passing the result of 'VBoxManage list runningvms' through grep, sed, and tr filters (and combinations), but I get the same results.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE in response to comment about more quotes.

Tried this:

```
for i in $(VBoxManage list runningvms); do echo "$i"; done
"Windows
7"
```

I also tried this:

```
for i in $(VBoxManage list runningvms); do VBoxManage guestproperty get "$i" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/1/V4/IP"; done
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '"Windows'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Could not find a registered machine named '7"'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBox, interface IVirtualBox, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 93 of file VBoxManageGuestProp.cpp
Value: 192.168.8.110
```

This last example is confusing... as you can see it return the same 2 errors, but then it does return the correct result.

UPDATE Correct solution

Thanks to everyone! Ivan X gave me the final key I needed to get the following (for anyone else that might need it):

```
for vm in "$(VBoxManage list runningvms)"; do echo $vm; done
Ubuntu 14.04 Server {1234sdfgh-sdfg-ertyu-...}
```

Comment: USE MORE QUOTES ! `VBoxManage guestproperty get "$i"`

Comment: I've tried your suggestions, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to wrap the quotes around the $().

```
for i in "$(VBoxManage list runningvms)"; do echo $i; done
```

output:

```
"Debian 7.6.0 32-bit" {82ec6db6-58b3-4b4c-aac8-d1b488fbe3e6}
```

Alternatively, you can set `IFS=''` before running the command, and then you don't need to use quotes (but you might find unexpected effects elsewhere).

Comment: You're welcome! If you're happy with the answer, I'd love if you could click the hollow checkbox to mark it as answered. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in $(VBoxManage list runningvms | tr -s '\r\n' ' '); do echo $i; done
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I got the same results.  I also tried '\r', '\n', and '\r\n'.  Is it possible the line break chars are in an unexpected format?